# Overlay 2 Axes together

Tags: graphics, manipulate, graphics3d

I am trying to generate a picture similar to the second one found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html) to illustrate the idea of a rotation matrix defining a new coordinate system. The problem is showing both the original (standard cartesian) set of axes and the transformed (45 degree clockwise about the z axis) axes together in 3D without manually making them a graphic and drawing each axis line. Preferably, I would be able to color the axes, but this isn't strictly necessary.

As a minor other note, if the solution is possible without using some of the more advanced features, that would be prefered.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point could be:

```
\[Theta] = \[Pi]/6;
pts1 = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}};
pts2 = RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}][#] & /@ pts1;
Graphics3D[Join[{Black, Thickness[0.007], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, 
{Red,Arrow[#] & /@ pts1}, {Blue, Arrow[#] & /@ pts2}], Axes -> True, 
Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

### Add

Interactive rotation:

```
Manipulate[
pts1 = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}};
pts2 = RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}][#] & /@ pts1;

Graphics3D[Join[{Black, Thickness[0.007], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]},
{Red,Arrow[#] & /@ pts1}, {Blue, Arrow[#] & /@ pts2},
{Text[Style[#[[1]], 14, Bold, Black], #[[2]]] & /@ {{"x", {1.3, 0, 0}},
{"y", {0, 1.3, 0}}, {"z", {0, 0, 1.3}}}}, 
{Text[Style["x'", 14, Bold, Blue], 
 RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}][#] & /@ {{1.1, 0.2, 0}}]},
 {Text[Style["y'", 14, Bold, Blue],RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}][#] & /@ 
 {{-0.2, 1.1, 0}}]},
 {Black, InfiniteLine[#] & /@ pts2}], 
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 PlotRange -> ConstantArray[{-1.1, 1.1}, 3],
 PlotLabel -> "Rotation angle \[Theta] = " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@\[Theta]] <> " rd"],
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/50}
]
```

[image]

Comment: While this gives most of the visual I want, I would like the transformed axes to be ruled (in order to drive home the transformed coordinates),just  like the axes drawn when you tell graphics `axes-> True`, and behave similarly.

Comment: @BrandonMyers see my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, not a full reproduction of the linked image.

None of these are advanced features, but it does require drawing the lines manually.

```
i = {1, 0};
j = {0, 1};

originArrow[pt_] := Arrow[{{0, 0}, pt}];

i2 = RotationMatrix[45 Degree].i;
j2 = RotationMatrix[45 Degree].j;

Graphics[{Black, 
  Text["x0", i, {-1, 0}], Text["y0", j, {0, -1}],
  Red, originArrow@i, originArrow@j,
  Black, 
  Text["x'", i2, {-1, 0}], Text["y'", j2, {0, -1}],
  Blue, originArrow@i2, originArrow@j2}]
```

[image]